# What is the difference between a CDK construct and a regular class?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am a new AWS CDK user. I am trying to understand the point of a CDK construct. I know that a CDK stack maps directly to a CloudFormation stack. I also know that a construct's purpose is to encapsulate multiple resources that work together. But since we are using real programming languages, why can't we just use a regular class to encapsulate related resources?

Comment: Don't really get your question, what do you mean with "use a regular class to encapsulate related resources"? Lowest-level constructs (L1) in CDK represent a cloud formation resource, higher-level constructs (L2) are provided by CDK for better usability. When you use CDK e.g. in Typescript each construct is also a class.Did you read the construct explanation from AWS? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/constructs.html

Comment: My question is more about the constructs that I create myself. Let's say that I want to create an SQS queue and a lambda that consumes from the SQS. These two resources should be encapsulated together. Now I could create a `class QueueLambda` or I could create a `class QueueLambda extends Construct` to encapsulate these two resources. What is the advantage of the latter to the former?

Comment: The difference between a regular class and an extended Construct class are the methods provided in the Construct class, which are essential for CDK if you want to build/synth your Construct.

Comment: Do you have some example methods?